# Recursive use of the Axiom of Choice

Tags: compactness, axiom-of-choice

In a standard proof that any sequence-compact metric space $(X,d)$ has a (finite) $\varepsilon$-net, the approach is the following: Make a sequence $(x_n)$ such that
$$
x_{n+1}\notin\bigcup_{i=1}^n B_\varepsilon(x_i)
$$
for all $n$, where $B_r(y)$ is the open ball of radius $r > 0$ around $y\in X$. Then prove that $(x_n)$ has no convergent subsequence.

The question is: **Can we be sure that we can choose such a sequence?** It is obvious that we must somehow make use of the Axiom of Choice, but in my opinion, it is not at all obvious that you can use that axiom *recursively* like this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don’t even need the full axiom of choice for this argument: the [axiom of dependent choice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_dependent_choice) ($\mathsf{DC}$) is sufficient.

Given $\epsilon>0$, let $\Sigma$ be the set of all finite sequences $\sigma$ in $X$ such that if $\sigma=\langle x_0,\ldots,x_{n-1}\rangle$, then

$$x_k\notin\bigcup_{\ell<k}B_\epsilon(x_\ell)$$

for each $k<n$. Define a relation $R$ on $\Sigma$ by $\sigma\mathrel{R}\tau$ if and only if $\sigma$ is a proper initial segment of $\tau$ (equivalently, $\sigma\subsetneqq\tau$). $R$ is a total relation on $\Sigma$, so by $\mathsf{DC}$ there is a sequence $\langle\sigma_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ in $\Sigma$ such that $\sigma_n\mathrel{R}\sigma_{n+1}$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$. Then $\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}\sigma_n$ is an infinite sequence $\langle x_k:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ in $X$ such that $$x_k\notin\bigcup_{\ell<k}B_\epsilon(x_\ell)$$ for each $k\in\Bbb N$.

In fact it’s only when you need to make infinitely many arbitrary choices, recursively or otherwise, that you need any part of the axiom of choice: you can always make any finite number of arbitrary choices.

Comment: Someone else telling me something new is better than myself realising what should have been obvious. Therefore, your answer will be the accepted one.

Comment: I am always inspired by your answers. Thank you, Prof. Scott.

Comment: @Hermis14: Thank *you*!

Answer (score 2):

I thought it a bit more through myself, and I guess it is in fact not that hard: Pick a choice function $f$ on (say) $\mathscr P(X)\setminus\{\varnothing\}$, where $\mathscr P(X)$ is the power set of $X$ (another option is a choice function on the set of all non-empty closed subsets of $X$). Then define the sequence $(x_n)$ recursively by
$$
x_{n+1} = f\Big(X\setminus\bigcup_{i=1}^n B_\varepsilon(x_i)\Big).
$$
That gives us the desired sequence.

In other words: Once we have the choice function, we can write down an explicit, recursive construction of $(x_n)$ without further use of the Axiom of Choice.

Comment: Yes, this is precisely how $\mathsf{AC}$ is used in this context. And you don’t need its full strength: see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It might be worth adding that you *really* need the axiom of choice here (to a certain degree anyway).

In Cohen's first model of the axiom of choice there is an infinite Dedekind-finite subset of $\Bbb R$ which is dense. Namely, there is a set $D\subseteq\Bbb R$ which is infinite, but has no countably infinite subsets.

By this virtue alone it is clear why $D$ (with the induced metric) is sequentially compact, every sequence has only finitely many points, so at least one is repeated infinitely often. So every sequence has a convergent subsequence.

On the other hand, $D$ is dense in $\Bbb R$, so as a metric space the metric is unbounded, it certainly cannot have a finite $\varepsilon$-net for any choice of $\varepsilon$.