# Inductive definition of a function in a formal language

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, induction, first-order-logic

$
\newcommand{\emt}{\varnothing}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\dom}{\mathrm{dom}}
$
My new formal proof is updated at the end of the post:

I am trying to show the following proposition:

Let $I_n = \{i \in \N ~|~ i \le n \}$ and $X$ be a nonempty set.

**Claim**: If there is no bijection from $I_n$ onto $X$ for all $n \in \N$, then there is an injection from $I_n $ into $X$. In symbols,
$$
\forall n\in \N: |I_n| \neq |X|
\Rightarrow
\exists f \in \N \to X: f \text{ is an injection}
$$

**Attempted informal proof**:
Suppose $\forall n\in \N: |I_n| \neq |X|$. Because $X$ is nonempty, there is $x_1 \in X$. Suppose $X = \{x_1\}$. Then, we can construct $\{(1,x_1)\} = I_1 \times X$ that is a bijection from $I_1 $ to $X$, which is a contradiction. Therefore, there is $x_2 \in X$ that is different from $x_1$. Let $X = \{x_1, x_2\}$. We can construct the bijection $\{(1,x_1), (2, x_2)\}$ from $I_2$ onto $X$. This is a contradiction. We can repeat this process indefinitely, which implies the existence of an injection from $\N$ to $X$ (I think the conclusion is not rigorously derived though).

However, the problem is, I want the proof to be expressed in a formal first-order language. I've seen that some people call the process an inductive definition of a function. For instance,

> An injection $g: \N \to X$ can be defined inductively.

But I haven't seen the formal definition of the inductive definition, and the underlying logic behind this is not clear to me. How can we express the defining process of $g$ and is it possible in ZFC? I prefer the process to be expressed symbolically if possible.

This question is motivated by the answers by

1. [Figurinha](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1753934/334795)
2. [Shore](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4347562/334795).

**Update**:
Combining the comment of Schweber and the answers by [Couchy](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4359371/334795), and [Scott](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1163771/334795), I tried to make a proof by myself. This proof uses [DC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_dependent_choice). To make use of DC, the key is to define a set $Y$ and an *entire* relation $R$ on the set.

Let
$$
Y = \{f \subseteq \N \times X~|~ f \text{ is an injection}, \exists n \in \N : I_n = \dom f\}\\
R = \{(f, g) \in Y \times Y ~|~ f \subsetneq g\}
$$

We have to show that $Y$ is nonempty and
$$
\forall f \in Y: \exists g \in Y: f R g
$$
$Y$ is nonempty because $X \neq \emt$ and $\{(1,x_1)\} \in Y$ for some $x_1 \in X$. Let $f \in Y$. Then, $f$ is an injection and there is $n \in \N$ such that $I_n = \dom f$. We have now two possible cases: $f[I_n] = X$ or $f[I_n] \subsetneq X$. The former directly yields a contradiction because $f$ becomes a bijection between $I_n$ and $X$. By the latter, there is $z \in X$ that is not in $f[I_n]$. We can now construct the function $g = f \cup \{(n+1, z)\}$. It is easy to show that $g$ is an injection, from $I_{n+1}$ to $X$, strictly larger than $f$. Therefore, we have $f R g$.

Now, by DC, there is a sequence $h: \N \to Y$ such that $h_n R h_{n+1}$ for all $n \in \N$. Construct a function $l: \N \to X$ such that
$$
\forall n \in \N: l(n) = h_n(\max \dom h_n)
$$
It is easy to see that $l$ is injective.

Is this acceptable?

Comment: I hope you recommend some helpful materials about this topic, too.

Comment: When each "next step" is completely determined by the process so far, the **recursion theorem** (from set theory, not recursion/computability theory) does the job. When (as in this question) each step has some freedom, you generally need some form of the axiom of choice, such as the **axiom of *dependent* choice**.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thank you for the indeed helpful comment! I've once encountered the theorem when finding related theorems, but then I concluded that it is not really relevant to this problem. Could you demonstrate how the theorem can be applied specifically to this problem?

Comment: See the second sentence of my comment.

Comment: @NoahSchweber OK. I'll try :)

Comment: (And in fact note that for this specific question the axiom of choice is provably necessary: it's consistent with $\mathsf{ZF}$ that there are infinite sets into which $\mathbb{N}$ does not inject.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber Would you check my updated proof?

Comment: A bit cumbersome, but looks good!

Comment: @Couchy I really thank you for sparing time for me. But, I should apologize for temporarily not accepting your answers only because I don't fully understand the reasoning. It may take some more time.

Answer (score 1):

Any set $X$ that has a [well-ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-order) can be inducted on. In particular the set of natural numbers is well-ordered.

For a set to be well ordered means every subset has a least element.

If a set is well-ordered, we can prove the following [induction principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-founded_relation):

> $(\forall x.(\forall y<x. \phi(y))\implies \phi(x))\implies (\forall x.\phi (x))$.

Indeed consider the set $N = \{x\in X\ |\ \neg\phi(x)\}$ then because $X$ is well-ordered, $N$ has a least element $x_0$, but now for any $y < x_0$, $\phi(y)$ because $y\not\in N$. But by our hypothesis, this implies $\phi(x_0)$, a contradiction. This means that $N$ is empty, and therefore $\forall x. \phi(x)$.

---

Now, we can obtain the following recursion theorem:

> Suppose that for any $x\in X$, whenever there exists a function $f_x : X_{<x}\to Y$ (where $X_{<x} := \{y\in X\ |\ y < x\}$) we can extend it to a function $\hat f_x : X_{\leq x}\to Y$, then there exists a function $f : X\to Y$ whose restriction to $X_{<x}$ is $f_x$

by applying (I'll spare the details) the induction principle above with
$$\phi(x) := (\exists f_x:X_{<x}\to Y. \forall y<x. f_x\text{ is compatible  with }f_y)$$
where $f_x$ is compatible with $f_y$ if $f_x$ restricted to $X_{<y}$ agrees with the values of $f_y$.

---

Now the [well-ordering principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-ordering_principle) says the the natural numbers is well-ordered, thus we can apply the above induction and recursion principles.

For the natural numbers, this simply means that if we know how to extend any function $f_n:\mathbb N_{<n}\to Y$ to a function $\hat f_n:\mathbb N_{\leq n}\to Y$, then we obtain $f : \mathbb N\to Y$.

Note that the base case is given by extending $f_0 : \mathbb N_{<0}\to Y$, which vacuously exists, to a function $\hat f_0: \mathbb N_{\leq 0}\to Y$, which is equivalent to selecting a single element of $Y$.

Comment: Thank you for the elaborated answer. But how is the well-order on $X$ is defined?

Comment: Sorry this answer may have been too general. You don't define the well-order on $X$, you assume it exists. The point of this post is that you can do induction/recursion on any set on which you can define a well-ordering. The well order on $\mathbb N$ is the usual one, namely $0 < 1 < 2 < 3...$.

Comment: Does it mean that the proof assumes the well-ordering theorem?

Comment: No, the well ordering theorem is equivalent to the axiom of choice. It says that any set can be well ordered, but it is a bit useless because it doesn't tell you what the well-ordering is. In order to do induction/recursion in a useful way you need to know what the well-ordering is.

Comment: Another example of a well ordering is a lexicographic order on say $\mathbb N\times\mathbb N$

Comment: It is true that to prove your claim you will need the axiom of choice, but to well-order your $X$ (which is my $Y$), but that is different. If this is still confusing you should post a different question focusing on that.

Comment: I am struggling to make use of ideas that appear in this answer to draw my own proof.

Comment: Would you check my updated proof?

Answer (score 0):

An more concrete approach is to assume you have a function for every set $Y$:
$\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb N}$
$$\texttt{rec}_Y : Y\to (\N\to Y\to Y)\to\N\to Y$$
satisfying the following equalities:
$$\texttt{rec}_Y(z,s,0) = z\\
\texttt{rec}_Y(z,s,n+1) = s(n,\texttt{rec}(z,s,n)).$$

Then any recursive function from $\N$ to $Y$ can be defined with $\texttt{rec}_Y$ by specifying its first two arguments.

The existence of $\texttt{rec}_Y$ can be proved using the method I described in my other answer (the [recursion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion#The_recursion_theorem)).

Comment: I am sorry that the answer contains so many unfamiliar notations to me. Did you use $\to$ as the Cartesian product symbol, $\times$?

Comment: A function $f : X \to Y\to Z$ takes an $X$, and produces a function from $Y$ to $Z$, is the same as function $f':X\times Y\to Z$ through the process of [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying). So you could equivalently view $\texttt{rec}_Y :Y\times (\mathbb N\times Y\to Y)\times\mathbb N\to Y$.

Comment: OK. Parentheses might have helped me understand it :) Thank you.